# Copy Datatable to Clipboard

Tags: flutter, datatable, copy, clipboard

I want to create an option to right click on a datatable and select copy, to copy the whole datatable to the clipboard.
Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: The memory buffer has a limited size and if your database is, for example, 100 MB, it is a very bad decision to try to allocate it in memory. Try to make a dump and save it to a file

Comment: Hey, so I think there is some confusion. You mentioned dataBASE. I am talking about a datatable. Most likely it will be small enough to copy.

Comment: copy what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is i dont know how to copy an entire datatable.